# easier way to graph a barplot with SE

Tags: r, plyr

I hope someone could help in finding a shotcut for generating barplot with error bars. In general I do like this

```
# some dummy data
q <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(100,400,T), nrow=20)), 
c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","G","K","L","M","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U")) 

#I usually melt the data
library(reshape2)
a1 <- melt(q)

# summarize them
library(plyr)
a2 <- ddply(a1, c("variable"), summarise, mvalue = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          medvalue = median(value, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE),    
                                          n = sum(!is.na(value)),se = sd/sqrt(n))

#However, I got an error in generating se:
#Error in sd/sqrt(n) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

# then I plot the graph  
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sum1, aes(x=variable, y=mvalue, fill=variable))+
 geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mvalue-sd,ymax=mvalue+sd))+
 scale_fill_grey()
 # here i used the sd instead of se
```

Why did i got the error for `se`? Is there any way to save all these steps to generate barplots with error bars in a smarter way?

Comment: I never used `plyr` before but what's wrong with simply use `aggregate` from base R? The following seem to work `aggregate(value ~ variable, a1, function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                              medvalue = median(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                              sd = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                              se = sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))))`

Comment: thanks, david, could you show how to plot the data using ggplot?

Comment: Your code doesn't work with generated `se`?

Comment: by viewing the result , there is 2 variables only shown variable and mean

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the code returns `value.se` column too

Comment: #am i doing something wrong ## ggplot(q2, aes(x=variable, y=mean, fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se,ymax=value+se))+
scale_fill_grey()

Comment: I don't have time to validate this right now. I would suggest you look into @Khashaas answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddply` is almost fully defunct in the shade of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a1$variable <- as.character(a1$variable)
a1  %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(mvalue = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
            medvalue = median(value, na.rm=TRUE),
            sd = sd(value, na.rm=TRUE),    
            n = sum(!is.na(value)), se = sd/sqrt(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=variable, y=mvalue, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mvalue-se, ymax=mvalue+se))+
  scale_fill_grey()
```

Comment: found some way to add SE column manually using q3<-cbind(se = q2$sd/sqrt(q2$n), q2). still looking for more easier way to plot the graph,,

Comment: surprisingly, reinstalling R and Rstudio solved the problem !